# remove EOLs and spaces between two tags in xml files

Tags: xml, bash, formatting

I have a lot (more than 50) xml files with some lines (more than 30/40 per files) with incorrect formatting :

example, this:

```
<TAG1>
    <TAG_TO_FORMAT>
           a_random_string

    </TAG_TO_FORMAT>
    <AN_OTHER_TAG_TO_FORMAT>
                       an_other_random_string
    </AN_OTHER_TAG_TO_FORMAT>
    <OTHER_TAG>pifpafpouf</OTHER_TAG>

</TAG1>
```

should be transform into this:

```
<TAG1>
    <TAG_TO_FORMAT>a_random_string</TAG_TO_FORMAT>
    <AN_OTHER_TAG_TO_FORMAT>an_other_random_string</AN_OTHER_TAG_TO_FORMAT>
    <OTHER_TAG>pifpafpouf</OTHER_TAG>

</TAG1>
```

it doesn't matter if the new line before `</TAG1>` is still present, my key problem is that each pattern : `<TAG>random_string</TAG>` must be on one line (the random_string does not contain an EOL)

I couldn't find any tool in bash allowing me to perform this, so how could i do this in bash ? (or maybe in python but i would prefer bash).

Comment: awk could be really helpful here, definitely worth googling. The closest I could get was `awk '/<TAG_TO_FORMAT>$/{printf $0" ";next;}1' <your-filename-here>`.

Comment: I suggest to use `tidy` for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are command line tools like xmllint and tidy that can be used like this:

```
tidy -xml -iq somefile.xml
```

In theory xmllint can also do it, but xmllint doesnt work as described for me on OS X (dont have a Linux instance handy to test there at the moment):

```
xmllint --noblanks somefile.xml
```

Comment: tidy works fine and xmllint doesn't work on my Linux instance (centOs6.3)

Comment: I just add the option -wrap 0 to the command tidy since i had some lines (`<tag>string</tag>`) that exceeded 64 characters.

Comment: When you remove the `--format` and execute `xmllint --noblanks somefile.xml` instead. `xmlint` did the job on my Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 1):

Tidy does a reasonable job.  Another option is to throw on an xslt transform calling normalize-space()

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()|/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:sort select="@kname"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and I'd save that into a file and if from command line run

```
xsltproc normalize-space.xsl file.xml
```

or in a pipeline

```
run_some_command | xsltproc normalize-space.xsl - | xmllint --format -
```

xmllint --noblanks does not characterize all the space characters I want necessarily as 'ignorable'.  It's almost certainly technically correct, but not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Perl for this kind of task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = join "", <>; 
$text =~ s/>\s+([^\s].*?[^\s])\s+<\//>$2<\//;
print "$text";
```

Call it like this:

```
my.pl < input.xml > output.xml
```

Comment: I cannot know the value of TAG_TO_FORMAT, it can have different TAG with a bad formatting

Comment: Just match on text between closing and opening angular brackets then. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in sed:

```
x='TAG_TO_FORMAT'
sed -e '/<'"$x"'>/{:next;/<\/'"$x"'>/!{N;bnext;};s/\n//g;s/>\s*/>/;s/\S\s*</</;}'
```

When a line begins with the correct tag we go into a loop collecting lines until we find the closing tag. Then we erase all the newlines and clean up spaces anchored by > one one side, and < on the other.

Comment: I cannot know the value of TAG_TO_FORMAT, it can have different TAG with a bad formatting.

Comment: You should mention constraints like that in your question next time.